# Calculate distance between points and a line and assign it to a table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, distance

My question has two parts:

1. How can I calculate the distance between many points and a line (as you see in the photo) and then to assign the values on a table using QGIS?
2. The calculated distance values from the points that are located on the right side of the line, should have a negative sign (-) in front of the number. How can I define that?

I guess the only way to do these in QGIS is by creating script but I do not really know what to write on that.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: As per the [Tour], please ask only One question per Question. Coding questions are expected to contain code. The good news is that Python is a very easy language to learn.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Join by Nearest](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisjoinbynearest) with Point layer as layer 1 and line as layer 2 to get coordinates of the points and distance and coordinates of the line.

Then field calculate a new field with formula:

```
case
when "feature_x"<"nearest_x" then "distance"
else "distance"*-1
end
```

[image]